# Windows cd-key not authenticating after reinstall

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

after my ssd crashed, I has to reinstall my windows, then I reentered my windows 7 64bit SP1 from MSDNAA and it says: "a problem ocurred. Error 0xC004C020"

How should I proceed?

Comment: how many times have you used the key?

Comment: once to activate first. Then again when I reinstalled my windows after the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I clicked on the option to call the MS service and activate it. Windows gives a code, that you input on your phone and then you receive another code to input on your computer. This worked.

Comment: You can select your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah I know, just waiting for the cooldown

Answer (score 1):

The error you refer to, `Error 0xC004C020`, is due to: "The activation server reported that the Multiple Activation Key has **exceeded its limit**." -- [Microsoft Support](http://bit.ly/LokvMH).

The same page goes on to say the remedy or possible workaround is: "Contact the Product Activation Call Center to obtain a new MAK or to increase the activation limit on the existing MAK". Instructions on how to get the Product Activation Call Center phone number is found at this [Microsoft Support page](http://bit.ly/Lols7F).